# Ionic 4 Skip login page when auth is set

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-routing

I am trying to bypass the login page when the auth is set.
All things are working fine but whenever the auth is set the login page is shown for less than half a second and then it redirects to the desired page.
I **wanted** to open the desired page directly.
Here is the code snippet.

**App.component.ts**

```
import { LoginserviceService } from './account/login/loginservice.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private authenticationService:LoginserviceService,
    private router:Router,
    private screenOrientation:ScreenOrientation,
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT)

      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.authenticationService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
        if (state) {
          this.router.navigate(['menu', 'dashboard']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['firstpage']);
        }
      });

    });
  }
}
```

**LoginserviceService.ts**

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpParams, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

// import {ap} from 'rxjs/operator/map';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginserviceService {
  private login_URL = "some api call can't disclose.";
  // private login_URL = "http://localhost:8000";
  authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  private storageKey = "email";
  constructor(
    private http:HTTP,
    private storage : Storage,
    private plt: Platform) { 
      this.plt.ready().then(() => {
        this.checkUserState();
      });
  } 
  loginApi(email:string,password:string)
  {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      this.http.post(this.login_URL,  

        { //params},
        {//headers}
      ).then(response => {

        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);

        if(data.error === "Success" && data.status === "200")
        {
          this.storage.set(this.storageKey, email).then(() => {
            this.authenticationState.next(true);
          });
          resolve("Success");
        }
        else if(data.error === "Email password does not match" && data.status === "209")
        {
            resolve(response.data.error);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
      });
    })
  } 
  checkUserState()
  {
    this.storage.get("email")
    .then((data)=>{
      if(data !== null)
      // this.router.navigateByUrl('/menu/dashboard');
      this.authenticationState.next(true);
    })
  } 
  logout() {
    return this.storage.remove(this.storageKey).then(() => {
      this.authenticationState.next(false);
    });
  }
  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticationState.value;
  }
}
```

auth guard.ts

```
import { LoginserviceService } from './loginservice.service';


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthguardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public auth: LoginserviceService) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

Router

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'firstpage', pathMatch: 'full' },

  {
    path: 'menu',
    loadChildren: () => import('./menu/menu.module').then( m => m.MenuPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then( m => m.DashboardPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'firstpage',
    loadChildren: () => import('./firstpage/firstpage.module').then( m => m.FirstpagePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('./account/account.module').then( m => m.AccountPageModule)
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: A quick workaround is hiding splashscreen in subscription. Or you can have an authguard on login page you can check the state in that guard and redirect to correct page.

Comment: can you also share your angular router? router sets initial default behavior

Comment: @SergeyRudenko kindly check.

Comment: hey @Eldar I tried this, is this what were you telling 
```this.authenticationService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
        this.splashScreen.hide();
        if (state) {
          this.router.navigate(['menu', 'dashboard']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['firstpage']);
        }
      });
 
    });```
This didn't worked.

Comment: Hey, you shared the guard , but where is the router?:)

Comment: @Abhishek Did you get any solution?

Comment: yes, I changed the strategy for changing in app.component.ts by using the local storage instead of using the behavior subject.

Answer (score 0):

In yur service provide an observable instead of last emitted value from subject.

```
  export class LoginserviceService {
      private login_URL = "some api call can't disclose.";
      private stateObs : Observable<boolean>;
      authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
      private storageKey = "email";
      constructor(
        private http:HTTP,
        private storage : Storage,
        private plt: Platform) { 
        this.stateObs = this.authenticationState.asObservable(); // provide an observable
          this.plt.ready().then(() => {
            this.checkUserState();
          });

      } 

      isAuthenticated() { // return obsvervable instead last emited value
        return this.stateObs;
      }
    }
```

In your guard

```
export class AuthguardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public auth: LoginserviceService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated().pipe(
      map(isAuth => {
        if (!isAuth) {
          return false; // or you can redirect to login page this.router.navigate(["/login"])
        } else {
          if (route.url === "login url") // authenticated user but trying to reach login page
          {
            return this.router.navigate(["/to-home-page"]);
          } else { // another page
            return true; //it's ok.
          }
        }
      }));
  }
}
```

Comment: No still the login page is showing for a short interval of time

Answer (score 0):

Normally there should be always a default redirect and for example default could be your actual home page (such that if a user has auth token as valid one - they immediately go directly to your main page, while if they do not have credentials then 'login' page gets loaded forcing user to login before further action / use)

In your use case you have a default redirect directing user to firstpage from the very start you can try removing the first default redirect item in the routes array and then rely on app.component's constructor to define where user should go. This way you avoid the issue you have, but it will not be the best practice:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  <!-- { path: '', redirectTo: 'firstpage', pathMatch: 'full' }, -->
  {
    path: 'menu',
    loadChildren: () => import('./menu/menu.module').then( m => m.MenuPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then( m => m.DashboardPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'firstpage',
    loadChildren: () => import('./firstpage/firstpage.module').then( m => m.FirstpagePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('./account/account.module').then( m => m.AccountPageModule)
  },

];
```

Comment: getting a white screen after this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my experience with this problem. I solve it trying to save time calling the methods. Instead of just calling the method that checks the status of the user in the constructor it is already checking the status that saves time. I put an example using your code.

```
  constructor(
    private http: HTTP,
    private storage: Storage,
    private plt: Platform) {

    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      this.storage.get("email").then((data) => {
        if (data !== null) {
          this.authenticationState.next(true);
        } else {
          this.authenticationState.next(false);
        }
      })


      this.checkUserState();
    });
  }
```

and add a setTimeOut in  app.component.ts as a help (one second). and I'm using navigateRoot from navController I saw it in another post.

```
setTimeout(() => {
this.authenticationService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
    if (state) {
      this.nav.navigateRoot(['menu', 'dashboard']);
      //this.router.navigate(['menu', 'dashboard']);
    } else {
      this.nav.navigateRoot(['firstpage']);
      //this.router.navigate(['firstpage']);
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

you must call your auth guard I leave you an example of how I have it **using CanActivate**

```
const routes: Routes = [  {
path:'firstpage',loadChildren()=>import('./firstpage/firstpage.module').then(m=>m.FirstpagePageModule), canActivate : [AuthGuardService] }];
```

everything else is fine and this works for me sorry for my translations I use google translate i hope help you.